# component.find() not fetching component when used inside eventListner

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, event

I am communicating betweeen Lightning component and VF page used as iframe inside lightning component. The reference for this is here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html

The problem I am facing is that in doInit() of lightningComponent I am using component.find() to find another component using aura:id of that component. But this is getting failed and I get undefined as a result of component.find(). The strange part here is that the eventListner listens to event multiple times. The number of times it listens to event is equal to number of times lightning component is initiated. (i.e no. of time doInit() is executed). I think this is due to phenomenon explained here:

https://triangle717.wordpress.com/2015/12/14/js-avoid-duplicate-listeners/

However, my concern is that why does it not find the component 1st time itself?

> Lightning component:

```
<!-- some code -->
<c:ComponentToBeReferenced aura:id="sampleId" />
:
:<!-- some code -->
:
<iframe aura:id="vfFrame" src="{!v.frameSrc}" width="{!v.frameWidth}" height="{!v.frameHeight}" class="vfFrame" frameBorder="0"/>
:
:
<!-- some code -->
```

> lightning component controller:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {                
    helper.otherHelperMethod(component, event, helper);
    //Add message listener
    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {

    if(event.data.state == 'objectProcessed'){
        var comp = component.find('sampleId');  // return undefined
        comp.sampleMethod();                    // throws error here
    }
    });
},
```

> VF page script that throws event :

```
var lexOrigin = 'https://{!$CurrentPage.parameters.lcHost}';
sendToLC({'state':'objectProcessed', 'vfHost': "{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}"});

    //Send message to LC
    function sendToLC(message) {
        if(typeof(lexOrigin) !== 'undefined'){
            parent.postMessage(message, lexOrigin);
        }
    }
```

Note: The event is getting thrown only once from VF Page.

Note: I tried moving the code to afterRenderer without any success.

Comment: is `component` also undefined? also - you have 2 `event` attributes - try renaming one of them

Comment: @ItaiShmida : component is not `undefined`. Also, renaming did not work. I think I found the reason, added that as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time my component is loaded, a new event listener is added to `window` as its code is written in `init` of component. Also, there is no code for removing the event listener. So, when next time an event is thrown, the old event listener persists and that event listener has old copy of component in it. This listener first handles the event and as the component inside it is invalid, component.find() throws error. This happens till all the earlier event listeners handle the event until the current and correct event listener with valid component is executed.

To resolve the issue, following is the code I've used for removing the added event listeners:

> lightning component controller:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {                
    helper.otherHelperMethod(component, event, helper);
    var eventListner = function(event) {

        if(event.data.state == 'objectProcessed'){
            window.removeEventListener("message",eventListner);     //Remove event listner as listening is done.
            var comp = component.find('sampleId');  
            comp.sampleMethod();                    
        }
    };
    window.addEventListener("message",eventListner);
},
```